# Are file names allowed to use dots other than the one before the file extension?

Tags: files

I am checking the filename validity on Ubuntu computers. I want to check whether the file extension is correct.

- If the only valid dot is the one before the file extension, then this check is valid:

  ```
  example.endexample -> file extension is endexample
  ```
- But if a dot is allowed in the filename, then this check is invalid:

  ```
  example.continue.endexample -> file extension is continue.endexample
  ```

So is separating the value after the first dot in order to get the file extension enough?

Comment: Yes, multiple dots are allowed, and file extensions don't mean all that much in Linux.

Comment: A file name can have ANY character.  Even a linefeed or a enter. Special characters will require escaping or adding quotes for the whole file name. "I am checking file name validity on Ubuntu computers. " Why? There are no invalid filenames ;-)

Comment: `.................................` is a valid filename. Read `man basename`.

Comment: Dots are no problem at all. Just be aware that a leading dot makes the file or folder hdden in Linux and MacOS. But there are many other naming pitfalls when the files are shared with other OSes. Or even on Linux itself if special characters are not quoted/escaped correctly when used in commands or scripts etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to answer: Yes, dots are allowed everywhere in Linux filenames. Even "worse": Linux and Unix filenames don't necessarily have extensions expressed in the name of the file.

So you will probably find many "incorrect" or missing file extensions, since there are no rules for filename extensions as in Microsoft's systems.

You can find the general rules here: [Linux / UNIX: Rules For Naming File And Directory Names](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/)

Answer (score 2):

File extensions (and therefore dots) have no special meaning as such in Linux. By tradition we use `.sh` for a shell script, `.py` for a Python one, `.c` for a C-source text and so on. And also `.doc` and so on for compability with other OSs. But everything works fine without or with other extensions.

To verify what type a given file is, use the `file` command:

```
file somefilename
```

See [`man file`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/file.1.html) for further description.

Also, the shell will try to execute everything that has an execute-bit set in permissions, using the header of the file to decide how. For scripts this header is called a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and has the form:

```
#!/path/to/interpreter
```

If the shebang is missing, the interpreter/shell that is used is the same as the calling one.